# Replace a folder name using a contained file name

Tags: directory, rename, batch-rename

I have a thousand or so folders having random names. Every folder has at least one file with avi, mkv,srt or mp4 extension.
I intend to replace the random generated folder name by the first file name (without extension) contained on it. By the way the name of the files use to include () -  and other strange characters.
The script should, in my opinion:

1. Go into the folder
2. Get the first name without extension
3. Go out of the folder
4. Rename the folder using the new name
5. Recursive travel the folders as it may contain other subfolder

The 5th step may be override, though.
As I am a nerd in bash programming, I'd apreciate a hand. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, actually there are several folders, but as they are 30 or 40, it is not important to recursive do it. Can do it by hand.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, this is a spoiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020720/creating-directory-from-filename-and-move-bash And I strongly recommend to resolve yourself first.

Comment: In fact the solution provided will not work for me since names contains several "foreign" characters (ö, û,  accnts, blank spaces...) and, they are not conained in the same directory. There are two or more files in every folder and, as I said, near a thousand different folders.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: solution 1) Regex contains meta characters; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436539/can-i-create-a-regex-set-in-containing-meta-characters solution 2) Choosing the way you think the filenames are identical (I can't help without examples.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
$ tree
.
├── eYRlzR8Ibk
│   ├── Awnluslskl
│   │   └── ö, û, accnts.avi
│   ├── baz
│   └── xyz.mp4
└── wHKEWxFgIt
    └── foo bar.srt

3 directories, 4 files
```

then

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -execdir sh -c '
  for d; do
    set -- "$d"/*.*
    [ -e "$1" ] || continue
    f="${1##*/}"
    mv -n -- "$d" "${f%.*}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

resulting in

```
$ tree
.
├── foo bar
│   └── foo bar.srt
└── xyz
    ├── baz
    ├── ö, û, accnts
    │   └── ö, û, accnts.avi
    └── xyz.mp4

3 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: Nice solution. I think, it should be accepted

Comment: Simple, working and elegant solution. Furthermore, incredible fast.
Congratulations and, also, thank you ver much.

Answer (score 0):

The script 
Copy/paste the script in your text editor
Replace `~/test/testfolders3` in `sourcedir` variable by your directory name wich contains all the directories with files
Try it without `mv $oldname $newname` first time to see what should happen.
After editing you could just copy it from your text editor and past it in terminal window.

```
sourcedir=~/test/testfolders3
cd $sourcedir
files=$(find . -type f)
for f in $files
  do
    echo -e "0:Not modified file name:\t $f"
    bname=$(basename $f)                             # Get file's name without path to it
    filewe=$(echo $bname | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')       # Get file's name without extension
    echo -e "1:Filename without extension:\t $filewe"
    dir=$(dirname $f)                                # Get directory name where file is located
    echo -e "2:Parent file's directory:\t $dir"
    parfold=$(echo $(dirname $dir) | sed 's/.\///')  # Get file's parent directory's parent directory name with stripped `./` preffix
    echo -e "3:Parent-parent stripped dir:\t $parfold"
    olddir=$(echo $dir | sed 's@.*/@@')              # Get file's parent directory name without path to it (everything before the last `/` slash is stripped)
    oldname=$sourcedir/$parfold/$olddir              # Get current file's parent directory name with full path
    echo -e "4:Old folder name:\t\t $oldname"; 
    newname=$sourcedir/$parfold/$filewe              # Set new file's parrent directory name with full path
    echo -e "5:New folder name:\t\t $newname"
    mv $oldname $newname                             # Renames folders
  done
find $sourcedir -type f                              # Shows result
```

Sorry if it is not fully optimized. I'm not programmer. It's only a compilation of different answers I've found to write it. It took a lot of time, because of I do not do it frequently.

It does not check now if directory exists. So being renamed once by the first moved file's name it will just throw a message like this:

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/lkjskd': No such file or directory
```

The first moved file does not mean the first in alphabetical order.

Here's result of `find $sourcedir -type f` command execution:

```
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/file3/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/file1/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/file2/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/file3/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/file1/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/file2/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/soft/soft.ware
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/soft/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/inter/inter.pol
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/inter/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/file2/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/file2/ser.seg
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/file3/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/file1/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/file2/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/kata/kata.ptx
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/kata/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/sinaps/sinaps.rtf
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/sinaps/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/file2/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/file2/tema.txt
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/file2/fan.in
```

Previous folders' names:

```
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/kjakd/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/jafklsjdkl/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/kjakd/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/jafklsjdkl/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/folders/lkjskd/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders3/lkjskd/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/kjakd/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/kjakd/ser.seg
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/jafklsjdkl/soft.ware
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/jafklsjdkl/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/kjakd/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/jafklsjdkl/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/folders/lkjskd/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/lkjskd/inter.pol
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders2/lkjskd/file3.mp4
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/kjakd/file2.mkv
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/kjakd/tema.txt
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/kjakd/fan.in
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/jafklsjdkl/kata.ptx
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/jafklsjdkl/file1.avi
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/lkjskd/sinaps.rtf
/home/user/test/testfolders3/folders/lkjskd/file3.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the try. It didn't work for me, unfortunately. Anyway another person (see above) proposed a simple working solution, Also thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Vidal accept his answer and upvote it. It is his reward)

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. I have alredy -now- accepted and upvoted (I think) the solution provided.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Steelworker (see above) worked perfectly, fast and smooth. A very clean and simple code.
You guys are incredible. Thanks for your time and dedication.
Best regards.